# How do I limit socket speed in C?

Tags: c, performance, sockets, ftp, bandwidth-throttling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you throttle the bandwidth of a socket connection in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235762/how-do-you-throttle-the-bandwidth-of-a-socket-connection-in-c)

I'm writing a simple FTP server in C for a Unix environment.  As a feature of the server, I want to limit the upload/download speed of a user.

1. Are there any library functions directly solve this problem?
2. If not, what's the algorithm used in a production FTP server? I have a very naive solution: calculate how many bytes to send in a second, say `x`, `write(x)` or `read(x)`, and then `sleep(1)`.

There should be a better solution.  Even better if there are code samples.

To be clear, I'm using Mac OS X, but I wish it could also run under Ubuntu or some Linux.

Comment: *"As a feature of the server, I want to limit the upload/download speed of a user"* - That sounds like an awesome feature

Comment: This question might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235762/how-do-you-throttle-the-bandwidth-of-a-socket-connection-in-c

Comment: @skjaidev I'm using Mac OS X, but I wish it could also run under Ubuntu or something

Comment: Aaarrgghhh!!!!  Don't do the "sleep (1)".  *Please* don't do the "sleep (1)"! ;)  See what your OS provides in terms of QoS and throttling capabilities (you didn't mention which OS you're running).

Comment: You might also wish to look at "tcpnice":  http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/dahlin/software/2002-nice.html

Comment: sleep(1) will have unintended side effects if you are handling more than one FTP session per thread.

Answer (score 0):

FTP is a application layer protocol . FTP can run on TCP or UDP sockets. (EDIT: tftp and [uftp](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net) runs on udp, pls see the comment section for details)

The Socket Speed is a function of following :

1. link Speed :10/100 Base T and so on.
2. BER of the link : Bit Error rate (typically in today's world its generally low 10 to the power -9 or something of that sort . there are burst errors as well.
3. Socket Buffer sizes : `/proc/sys/net/core` parameters

On linux : For handling the TCP Sockets here's a good article [1]

4.Tweak the stack to filter/drop packets to introduce the packet loss , thus eventually throttling the flow rate :  Tools like **netem**[2] help you adjust the buckets to throttle the flows.

[1] http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/

[2] http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem

Comment: "FTP can run on UDP sockets"... this claim requires evidence.

Comment: To avoid the discussion from digression to FTP i didn't provide details there. 1. tftp runs on udp port 69 for speed. 2. There is uftp which is a multi cast file transfer that provides encryption for security.

Comment: TFTP transfers files, but it is not FTP.  Ditto uftp.

Comment: They are file transfer application layer protocols. Ofcourse the variants have their individuality. !!!!

Comment: The statement that FTP runs over UDP remains false.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you want to do this? 
Is your motive to annoy your users?  (this is a legitimate motive - see any of the several "free upload" sites)

Bandwidth limiting like this is not a good way to protect your server from overload.
people will find threaded clients and open concurrent FTP sessions...

*are there any library functions to do that?*

Probably not, bandwidth shaping is an OS task not a service task.

*what's the algorithm?*

The one you describe sounds fairly effective.

To make it better could look at how many octets have been read or written and how much time has been spent before deciding to sleep.  Consider the case where the client is slower than your limit: the reads and writes will end up blocking and your sleep() will just add unneccessary latency. this will also reduce hide effects of disk latency etc from the user.

You could consider using usleep or nanosleep for finer resolution
both are in posix so should be on OSX *BSD and linux.