# JavaScript / C++ - Is there a way to limit downstream of a program using code?

Tags: javascript, c++

I want to program a Windows Desktop Application which lets the user limit internet speed for individual programs (for example: Chrome, Steam), so one program is not using all the bandwidth for itself, using JavaScript. Is there a way to do this with JavaScript or C++. I would use the program Electron if I could program my Application with JavaScript.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you throttle the bandwidth of a socket connection in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235762/how-do-you-throttle-the-bandwidth-of-a-socket-connection-in-c)

Comment: You may be able to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142906/using-c-c-is-it-possible-to-limit-network-traffic for some inspiration.  Due to the layer you're looking to work with, you may have a lot of difficulty getting this to work with Electron.